# Automatically Match Woocommerce Product Images with Product Title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

After doing some research I found out that image titles and alt matters a lot for SEO and changing each image title and alt will take too long.

I found this code here but it did not affect the current images.

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2);

function change_attachement_image_attributes( $attr, $attachment ){
    // Get post parent
    $parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', $attachment);

    // Get post type to check if it's product
    $type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $parent);
    if( $type != 'product' ){
        return $attr;
    }

    /// Get title
    $title = get_post_field( 'post_title', $parent);

    $attr['alt'] = $title;
    $attr['title'] = $title;

    return $attr;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try `woocommerce_gallery_image_html_attachment_image_params` filter for the customization. Check following example. It fetches the product title and assigns it to the `alt` and `title` attribute of the image. Note: This only works in product single page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_image_html_attachment_image_params','wpso_customize_single_product_image' );

function wpso_customize_single_product_image( $details ) {
    global $product;
    $details['alt'] = $details['title'] = get_the_title( $product->get_id() );
    return $details;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Log in to your Phpmyadmin, select your database and run this query to update images titles:

```
UPDATE wp_posts as a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as b ON a.ID = b.meta_value
LEFT JOIN wp_posts as c ON b.post_id = c.ID
SET a.post_title = c.post_title
WHERE a.post_type = 'attachment'
AND a.post_mime_type = 'image/jpeg'
AND b.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
AND c.post_type = 'product'
```

... and this SQL query to update images alts:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta as z 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts as a ON z.post_id = a.ID 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as b ON a.ID = b.meta_value 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts as c ON b.post_id = c.ID 
SET z.meta_value = c.post_title 
WHERE z.meta_key = '_wp_attachment_image_alt' 
AND a.post_type = 'attachment' 
AND a.post_mime_type = 'image/jpeg' 
AND b.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
AND c.post_type = 'product'
```

Comment: I applied these codes and a couple of rows got affected but nothing has changed in the front end

Comment: @MohammadAlnahhas You should clear transients to make change in the Frontend. Run these queries: `DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE ('%\_transient\_%')`, `DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE ('%\_site_transient_\_%')`

Comment: I have no idea why is this not working for me, here is my website siphers.store

Comment: @MohammadAlnahhas check this product's thumbnail: https://siphers.store/product/xbox-live-gold-3-month/, the Alt was changed but not the Title. Maybe your theme is overriding WooCommerce template files. Go to your theme folder, find `product-image.php` file in `woocommerce`'s  subfolder.

Comment: What should I do with that file?

Comment: @MohammadAlnahhas It overrides the corresponding woocommerce file, I guess it's currently `echo` the images directly without calling to any hook (including filter and action).